# Xamarin Android: Shared MonoRuntime error

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin-test-cloud, azure-pipelines

I am developing an android app with Xamarin. I tested in successfully through emulator and in test cloud manually but when I am trying to run it through VSTS, I am getting:

> Mono Shared Runtime is not supported. This can be resolved by changing
>   the project configuration or using a Release build.

I checked my android project file, shared mono runtime is turned off.

Can anyone tell me what could cause this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: looks like you found a bug, StackOverflow is not a bug tracking system, please file the bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ attaching a self-contained minimal testcase

Comment: "I checked my android project file, shared mono runtime is turned off." that's an invalid statement. A project file can contain multiple profiles (debug/release and many more). Based on the error message you are running probably the debug profile. You should revise your VSTS configuration to switch to release profile if possible.

Comment: Well, what i meant was, the release mode of my android project has mono shared runtime turned off and just to be clear I also turned off mono runtime on debug mode as well to see if I am running on debug mode. But still no result.. Can you think of any possibilities which mightbe causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

AOT tag in my android solution was set to true. I had to disable it and run it on VSTS.

Comment: Same problem for me, What is AOT tag ? where is it?

Comment: Open your android's .csproj file. You will see AOT tag, remove it or set it to false.

Answer (score 4):

Right click to your Android Project -> Properties

[image]

Disable the option "Use Shared Runtime"

[image]

Comment: where i can find menu "Android Project" ?

Answer (score 0):

After removing Shared Runtime and Fast Deployment from Android Options, I had to restart Visual Studio and switch again on Release configuration for the settings to take effect.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019 Preview